# CakePHP Cannot Pass Variable from controller that has Authentication

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to pass a working variable $count from a controller name dashboard which has authentication.. I tried to insert $this->Auth->allow('_getOnlineUsers'); so that none admin can use the function.

```
<?php
class DashboardsController extends AppController{
    var $name = 'Dashboards';
    var $uses = array('Bid', 'Account');


    function beforeFilter(){
        parent::beforeFilter();

        if(!empty($this->Auth)) {
            $this->Auth->allow('template_switch');
            $this->Auth->allow('_getOnlineUsers');
        }
    }

    function _getOnlineUsers(){
        $dir   = TMP . DS . 'cache' . DS;

        $files = scandir($dir);
        $count = 0;

        foreach($files as $filename){
            if(is_dir($dir . $filename)){
                continue;
            }

            if(substr($filename, 0, 16) == 'cake_user_count_') {
                $count++;
            }
        }

        return $count;
    }
```

then inside the same controller I pass the variable to onlineUsers

```
 $this->set('onlineUsers', $this->_getOnlineUsers());
```

then in my user.ctp I tried the following

```
 <?php echo $count;?>
 <?php echo $onlineUsers;?>
```

nothing happened please help
does location make a difference? because here's my destinations
controller/dashboards_controller.php

/alberta_template/elements/user.ctp

Comment: Are you sure the $count variable even has a value? Try returning some arbitrary text from your _getOnlineUsers method, such as return 'testing' rather than return $count.

Comment: yes it does work and have a value on the dashboard/admin side, I'm trying to get it on the user side as well.

Comment: although I tried <?php var_dump($onlineUsers); ?> it's returning null